# Bash - assign variables to output of a command in a loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, associative-array

I've got an application that runs and defines the devices on a system.  The output looks something like this:

```
./show-devices 192.168.1.2 | grep volume

/dev/sda        volumeid-65
/dev/sdb        volumeid-81
/dev/sdc        volumeid-92
```

What I'm trying to do is run the application in a loop and assign variables like so:

```
sda=volumeid-65
sdb=volumeid-81
sdc=volumeid-92
```

Then, be able to use the $sda, $sdb, and $sdc variables later on in the script.  Not all outputs are the same.  Some machines will only have one volume, some will have more.  All suggestions are welcome.  I've tried many combinations of a for loop and don't appear to be getting anywhere.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
eval `./show-devices 192.168.1.2 | grep volume | while read d v ;do
    echo $(basename $d)=$v
done`
```

However, you'll not be sure of the names of the variables. So it's better to use an associative array:

```
# declare the array
declare -A volumes

# Assign values to the array
eval `./show-devices 192.168.1.2 | grep volume | while read d v ;do
    echo volumes[$(basename $d)]=$v
done`

# Use the array
for i in "${!volumes[@]}"; do
    echo "Key:$i , Value:${volumes[$i]}"
    # Declare all the variables with the values as asked by question
    eval $i=${volumes[$i]}
done
```

**Explaination**: `| while read d v` loops over the output of the previous command reading 2 values per line. `basename $d` gives me the base name of the device and $v contains the volume associated with the device. This is assigned into the `volumes` associative array declared with `declare -A volumes`. The `while` loop runs ins a sub-shell and prints `volumes[sda]=...` and `eval` evaluates this in the current shell, actually assigning the value.

**Usage**: The `for` loop is a usage example. `"${!volumes[@]}"` is the list of keys for the `volumes` array, and the `for` loop loops over them and prints the value associated with each key in the `volumes` array.

**Edits**:

- Modified the `while` loop to echo the assigment and `eval` the whole thing (to get around the subshell being spawned by the pipe.
- Added usage info
- Added exact solution asked in question

Comment: Did you try that code? bash will execute the `while...` in a subshell; when the pipe terminates, so does the subshell along with its associated variables.

Comment: @rici You're right. Altering the solution to work around the subshell.

Comment: Thank you.  How do I reference or call the array later to use the items in it?

Comment: @MikeD the 2nd loop (the `for` loop) is an example of how to use the `volumes` array. I also modified the solution as per rici's suggestion.

Comment: @Samveen I see it now. Does this assign a variable, though?  My output looks like this in shell:

sdc : volumeid-92
sdb : volumeid-81
sda : volumeid-65

What I wanted to do was to use $sda, $sdb, and $sdc as variables assigned to its corresponding volume identifier on the same line.

Comment: @Samveen alright, I'm understanding that part.  So how am I to take each and assign variables from my initial question?  Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @MikeD First code gives you variables `sda`, `sdb`, `sdc`. Second code also gives you the same, but also gives you the option to use `volumes["sda"]`, `volumes["sdb"]`, `volumes["sdc"]` as well. Please note that I have modified both after your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
source <(
    ./show-devices 192.168.1.2 |
    sed -rn '/volume/{s#/dev/([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+#\1=#;p}'
)
```

This runs your command, passes it through sed to format it like shell assignments, and then uses a process substitution to treat the output like a file which is sourced into the current shell.